# Copy data from one table to another(joined)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a problem in sql, in particular I have to copy data from one table to another.
Tables have a 1-N relationship and I should copy a field, for example "weight" from table1 to all weight fields from table2 that are linked to the product.
I thought about doing as follows, but it didn't work for me:

```
insert INTO table2 (weight) 
select weight 
from table1 
where table1.product_source_id = table2.source_id;
```

Any of you have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why do you have two such similar tables? Do you really need to copy data around?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the db is postgress.
I had added a new column and I needed to put the weight in all the rows of table 2 linked to the product. This is an initial requirement as adding this field to table 2 implies several problems if not consistent with the product.

Answer (score 3):

You want an `update`, not `insert`.

A generic approach uses a correlated subquery:

```
update table2
    set weight = (select t1.weight from table1 t1 where t1.product_source_id = table2.source_id);
```

Specific databases might have other approaches.

In Postgres, this would more commonly use a `FROM` clause:

```
update table2
    set weight = t1.weight
from table1 t1
where t1.product_source_id = table2.source_id;
```